# PHP / MySQL - Safe characters for display names / usernames / passwords, with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, character-encoding, pdo

a bit of a PHP / MySQL newbie here...

I've been building a PHP-based site that uses a MySQL database for storing user information, like their display names, usernames, and passwords.

I've been learning about escaping, prepared statements and the like, and how to prevent SQL injections like "bobby'); drop table users--".

I'm using PDO prepared statements to get user input from forms, in order to register them into the DB. However, I need to know a few things:

1. Since I am using prepared statements, for display names, usernames,
   passwords, etc, is it okay for me to allow special characters like
   @, #, $, or even 'single' or "double" quotes? And what about spaces,
   international characters, characters with accents, or things like ♥
   ? And when I ask if it's "okay" to allow these characters, I'm
   wondering if there are any further security risks that may arise
   from allowing quotes or parentheses in people's usernames, or things
   like html tags for bold or italics?
2. If it is okay to allow *most* special characters, but not *some*: are
   there any specific "dangerous" characters (in the scope of MySQL)
   which I absolutely need to make illegal? (I feel like quotes may fit
   this agenda, but I'm getting mixed signals on that.)
3. If I were to allow characters outside of the typical "alphanumeric
   and underscore" range, are there any pitfalls I may experience later
   (in MySQL, SQL, or PHP) from allowing strange characters? Will I
   need to somehow make html tags appear as strings, rather than actual
   tags, when displaying people's usernames? Or would I need to escape
   quotes in people's usernames whenever I wanted to query with them?
   Or does none of this matter since I'll be using prepared statements
   with PDO?
4. Do charsets like utf8 or utf16 come in anywhere, in making it so I
   can accept the widest range of display names and usernames, while
   still making sure those alphabets can be rendered on my website?
5. I know that there are some Cyrillic letters that look identical to
   English ones. I used to copy these straight out of MS Word and use
   them in my usernames. I realize that these can be used to
   perceptually-impersonate other members, simply by swapping out an
   English "a" for a Cyrillic "a". Usernames with ♥ in them may be hard
   to search for if someone isn't well-versed in alt-code. Should this
   be a concern? What is your opinion on this?

Thanks in advance to whoever can give me some insight on this.

Comment: Please limit your posts to one question at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me say that I really like your style. It appears that most people don't take the time to think these things through, and just slap together queries with no data sanitization at all. So congratulations on being diligent. :)

That said, with PDO, you shouldn't have to to worry about quotes messing up your queries. Especially if you bind your variables with [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), which allows strict parameter control. With that you can cast the variable type, and length. Also, special characters will not mess up your query, as PDO escapes them, too. So no need to worry about that.

As for making HTML appear as text instead of actual HTML, a very useful function is [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), which will convert html code to character codes. This function can also be used with the optional ENT_QUOTES flag, which turn this `"` into this `&quot;`. htmlspecialchars() also has an option to set the output to the encoding of your choice.

Comment: but also, just trusting `htmlspecialchars` can be dangerous too: http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2012/03/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-cross-site-scripting-xss-in-php-part-1-how-not-to-use-htmlspecialchars-for-output-escaping/

Comment: Thanks; this answers my "overall" question quite well. :)

Answer (score 4):

This [SQL Injection Cheat Sheet](http://ferruh.mavituna.com/sql-injection-cheatsheet-oku/) has several examples of MySQL queries you can test while still in development.

It's a great resource for learning about some of your questions on what is "Acceptable", and you have to consider the entire lifecycle of "a piece of data".

Typically a piece of data might start in a **HTML form** and then get **POSTed** to your PHP script (so, if the user wants they can just POST data directly without the form).
Then your php script (hopefully) **sanitizes** the data, then it is **Stored**.

While in the database, you might be doing **backup** operations, saving it to an **SQLDump**, or some other sort of maintenance.

Then obviously the data will be **Read** at some point, if it's a markdown language it might get **compiled**, and eventually it is sent to someone's browser where it's probably **injected into html** and **displayed**.

As you can see there are a whole lot of places in a piece of data's lifecycle where things can go awry. If you fail to consider all of these, you may see some common errors like backslashes that pile up on themselves each time you save/load the data.. sql errors, becoming vulnerable to attacks, etc.

What kind of data do you want to support? That's up to you. Just make sure you'd handling it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the link; though that page looks intimidating, it also looks like a useful security resource for my project. I appreciate the overview on the data life cycle, too; gives me a less vague idea of the "big picture," as I (rather loosely) currently understand it :P